# drupal---the $page variable node.tpl.php

Tags: drupal, variables

```
 <?php if (!$page): ?>
  <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h2>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

the code is used to make a decision  if the displayed page is a full page state. if $page is true( a full page state) , then !$page is false. the following code is executed. but i saw the following code's result is output to the full page state not the node's page. why?

i find in each article's page. the article's tilte is controled by the page.tpl.php. why it's not controled by the node.tpl.php. as a fact, an article is a node,which shows should control by the node.tpl.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `page.tpl.php` there you are also printing `<?php print $title ?>` which prints the title of the page, not the node, which is either a node/article is `$page` is true, or the username in case you're viewing `http://mysite.com/user` page, or "Request new password" in case you are on the `http://mysite.com/user/password` page.

It's because of this you shouldn't print the title in `node.tpl.php` if the `$page` is true, because this will print the title twice.

The node/article title should only be printed as a linked title when `$page` is false, so it's printed along with the node teaser or body, and the page title in this case will be the main title printed from `page.tpl.php`.